# ObservableList to TableView javafx

Tags: javafx

I'm programming with a library that I don't know the code, only the methods, and I can't modify it. I tried to make a tableview of "flights" and it works but I don't know how to put a name(or ID) for each fly. Can someone help me? Thanks. Some code here:

```
public class StageController {

    @FXML  private TableView<Flight> flightsTable;
    @FXML  private TableColumn<Flight, String> flightColumn;   


public void start(Airport air){
        final AirportFlights a = Data.getInstance().getAirportFlights(air);
        ObservableList<Flight> flights = FXCollections.observableArrayList(a.getArrivals().getFlights().values());
        flightsTable.setItems(flights); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a `valueFactory` for your tablecolumn. If you have a field `name` inside your `Flight` class then, you can do :

```
flightColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                   new PropertyValueFactory<Flight, String>("name"));
```